# Apply a function across multiple columns of one dataframe using input from another dataframe (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have some large dataframes with a mix of characters and characters as numerics I'm trying to quickly calculate frequencies for without utilizing a loop.

Let's use the following dataframe as an example for the sake of this question:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = paste0("SubID_", 1:((100))),
  score = as.character(sample(1:100, 100, replace=TRUE)),
  dob = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 100)
)
```

I used the following function to find the most frequent value in the data:

```
  # Taken from:
  # https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_mean_median_mode.htm
  mode <- function(v) {
    uniqv <- unique(v)
    uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
  }
```

To get an output like the following:

```
    f <- data.frame(sapply(df, mode))
      sapply.df..mode.
id             SubID_1
score               84
dob              10739
```

Where the row names are basically the column names from the initial dataframe. (It's all getting appended to one file for a data summary report).

What I'd like to do from here is get an estimate of how much of the data is comprised of the most frequent score, which I attempted to do with the following function:

```
  frequencycounter <- function(x,df,f){
  sum(str_count(df[,x], f[x,]))/length(df[,x])
  }
```

Where "x" is character value representing a column name.

However, whenever I try lapply or sapply on it, it takes a while to run to completion:

```
    lapply(colnames(df),frequencycounter,df=df,f=f)
    lapply(list(colnames(df)),frequencycounter,y=df,z=f)
    sapply(colnames(df),frequencycounter,df=df,f=f)
```

I'm sure there's a `mutate` or `mdplyr` solution to call summarize which is much faster than this, but it just isn't jumping out at me.

Comment: In the end, what is your expect output? A frame, a named list/vector, or something else? Much of this seems a bit roundabout, where `sort(table(df$score), decreasing=TRUE)[1]/nrow(df)` gives `0.05`, which is the proportion of data that has the max `score`. This could be extended to all columns with `lapply(df, function(z) sort(table(z), decreasing=TRUE)[1]/nrow(df))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can modify the `mode()` function that you provided:

```
mostfrequent <- function(v){
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))/length(v)
}
data.frame(sapply(df, mostfrequent))
      sapply.df..mostfrequent.
id                        0.01
score                     0.04
dob                       0.01
```